# VC++ DLL project start an external program for debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I am looking at projects properties, but where do I mention what external program to open to start DLL's debugging?

Comment: Why did you develop that DLL? To use in some application, right? Then why are you asking such question. Debug that application!

Comment: Sometimes the application is an external program.  For example, I'm currently debugging code that is called by a MATLAB interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Command

Answer (score 0):

You debug a *process*.

You can step through any code that has symbols available, whether that code is in the .exe or in a .dll called by the .exe.

The main issue you might run in to is debugging "managed code" (i.e. byte code in a .Net dll or exe) vs "unmanaged code" (actual Intel x86 instructions).  If your project consists of a combination of both kinds of binaries, then you'll need to do "mixed mode debugging".

Here's more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd